# Is "It's not fair on me" grammatically correct?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

Is the following sentence grammatically correct:

> It's not fair on me.

I've just heard it in a Scottish movie and I thought it sounded quite odd. 
I thought the proper way to say it is "It's not fair to me."

Comment: In the US, _to me_ is definitely the "correct" option.  It is possible, however, that _on me_ is a local idiom.  Did the speaker have a strong accent?  If so, it is possible that the speaker said _to me_ but it came out sounding like _on me_ to one not used to a Scottish accent.

Comment: 'Fair on someone' (negative polarity) is still quite common in the UK.

Comment: In Australia, "fair on me" can be heard as well. I can't say whether it is strictly correct in American English though.